# Present UIVideoEditorController full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uivideoeditorcontroller

I have implemented video recording using AVFoundation successfully, after the video recording is over I want to allow user to clip the recorded video to enable that I am using

```
UIVideoEditorController
```

But the problem is that it gets presented as a popover I want to present it full screen how can I do this?

Are there any other options other than this for allowing video clipping.

Comment: did you got the solution?

Comment: By adding this line you can present this controller to full screen

videoEditorController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

Comment: But i am not abe to save. By pressing Save button it always calling didCancel delegate method. Do any one facing same issue. I would really appriciate if anyone provide a workaround of my issue. Thanks